# Lumen Artisan Issue: No memcached servers added

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

I have just begun to work in a working project. I was trying to mount a docker-compose set of servers for DB, Lumen, and more. When I try some command involving artisan (just like `php artisan --version`or `php artisan migrate`) I get the error message:

> No memcached servers added

Well, then I go to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache#configuration) to see how memcached cache driver works and it says that this is configured in `config/cache.php`. Well, this project has no cache.php file. In the other hand, the .env file does not contain CACHE_DRIVER environment variable.

I tried mounting a memcached server dockerized, but still same error. Where can I configure the memcached server nor socket in the project if I don have any configuration related to memcached???

Could this be happening 'cause Laravel finds no cache configuration and it selects any driver with no configuration?

Comment: Lumen HAS artisan commands (install a project and you will see artisan file). And lumen cache documentation referrs to Laravel docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could reach the solution by myself. Thanks everybody for watching.

When a Lumen project has no .env file configuration files gets some strange configurations. In this case was using memcached as server driver.

Solution: Create a .env file and set the cache driver.